# Fatal error: Call to a member function authorise() on a non-object

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have this error while trying to improve PHPMailer for sending automatic emails in my website:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function authorise() on a non-object in /home/u289995868/public_html/es/php/class.user.php on line 116

The 'corrupted' code in the file is this:

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
    {      
        require_once 'mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
        require_once 'mailer/class.pop3.php';
        $pop->authorise('mx1.hostinger.es', 110, 30, 'admin@barreeeiroo.ga', 'xxxxxxxx', 1);
        $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->isHTML(false); 
        $mail->Host = 'mx1.hostinger.es';
        $mail->From = 'admin@barreeeiroo.ga';
        $mail->FromName = 'Admin de barreeeiroo.ga';
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
```

Corrupted line is `$pop->authorise(...);`.

You can take a look to the `require_once` files here: [GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

*Thanks for the answer.*

Comment: there are no object $pop inside your function visibility scope

Comment: you should probably add the code of the required file, so that the answer will always fit the reason. If you don't, no one will understand this question post update.

Comment: Like Unex says - if you had posted your code in your Github issue, you might have got an answer.

Comment: I didn't posted an issue on Github; I taged that Github repository because I imported that code, that's it

Comment: So I imagined [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/780)?

Comment: No, but if you read down, I posted that the code that provided Alex Giuvara has solved my problem

Comment: BTW this code, and the selected answer will not work on recent versions of PHPMailer because you're not using an autoloader or loading the SMTP class. If you're using an old version, update it, and base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$pop cannot be used outside of popBeforeSmtp() method. Try:

```
require_once 'mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'mailer/class.pop3.php';
$pop = new POP3;
$pop->authorise('mx1.hostinger.es', 110, 30, 'admin@barreeeiroo.ga', 'xxxxxxxx', 1);
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->isHTML(false); 
$mail->Host = 'mx1.hostinger.es';
$mail->From = 'admin@barreeeiroo.ga';
$mail->FromName = 'Admin de barreeeiroo.ga';
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->addAddress($email);
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Simpler to use the `POP3::popBeforeSmtp()` static wrapper. This code won't work on recent versions of PHPMailer because it lacks the autoloader and thus will not be able to use SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$pop` is not initialized within your function so what you are actually doing is `null->authorise(...);`, which makes no sense.